# Eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix with known column/row $l^2$-norm

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms, symmetric-matrices

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a symmetric matrix. Suppose we use the notation $a_{i}$ for the $i$-th row (or column, which would be the same given its symmetry), with $i\in\{1, ... , n\}$.

Suppose, in addition, that $A$ has the property that $\Vert a_i \Vert_2^2 < 1$, for every $i$.

I have the following queries:

- Can we say something about the eigenvalues of $A$?
- Ideally, can we link this property to $A$ being (or not) positive-definite?

Many thanks!

Comment: If $A$ symmetric, its eigenvalues are real.

Comment: The norm of the columns gives us an upper bound on the eigenvalues of $A$ and their sum. No, we cannot say anything about whether $A$ is positive definite on the basis of this information.